# Create Corpus by combining words in r

Tags: r, nlp, text-mining

I am trying to create corpus, but in that I wants to combine 2 consecutive words in document, I didn't want corpus of single words.

I am using below script. Is there a way in which I can create corpus "docs" which will be inclusion of combined 2 consecutive words in each document? Please advise.

```
library(plyr)
library(tm)
library(e1071)

setwd("C:/Assignment/Assignment-Group-Prediction/IPM")

training<- read.csv("Data.csv",header=T,na.strings=c(""))

Res_Desc_Train <- subset(training,select=c("Group","Description"))

##Step 1 : Create Document Matrix 

docs <- Corpus(VectorSource(Res_Desc_Train$Description))
docs <-tm_map(docs,content_transformer(tolower))

#remove potentially problematic symbols
toSpace <- content_transformer(function(x, pattern) { return (gsub(pattern, " ", x))})
removeSpecialChars <- function(x) gsub("[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]","",x)
docs <- tm_map(docs, toSpace, "/")
docs <- tm_map(docs, toSpace, "-")
docs <- tm_map(docs, toSpace, ":")
docs <- tm_map(docs, toSpace, ";")
docs <- tm_map(docs, toSpace, "@")
docs <- tm_map(docs, toSpace, "\\(" )
docs <- tm_map(docs, toSpace, ")")
docs <- tm_map(docs, toSpace, ",")
docs <- tm_map(docs, toSpace, "_")
docs <- tm_map(docs, content_transformer(removeSpecialChars))
docs <- tm_map(docs, content_transformer(tolower))
docs <- tm_map(docs, removeWords, stopwords("en"))
docs <- tm_map(docs, removePunctuation)
docs <- tm_map(docs, stripWhitespace)
docs <- tm_map(docs, removeNumbers)
```

Comment: You might also want to try the tidytext package, which is easier to work with than the tm package (IMHO) and has a bigram feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [FAQ](http://tm.r-forge.r-project.org/faq.html#Bigrams) of the `tm` package answers your question directly:

> Can I use bigrams instead of single tokens in a term-document matrix?
>
> Yes. Package NLP provides functionality to compute n-grams which can be used to construct a corresponding tokenizer. E.g.:

```
library("tm")
data("crude")

BigramTokenizer <-
function(x)
  unlist(lapply(ngrams(words(x), 2), paste, collapse = " "), use.names = FALSE)

tdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(crude, control = list(tokenize = BigramTokenizer))
inspect(removeSparseTerms(tdm[, 1:10], 0.7))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. Yes, I am able to generate corpus using bigram tokenizer soutions which you suggested.

Comment: I'm glad it works. Don't forget to mark the answer as correct!